# Poster book to be printed

Tags: copyright, legal, book, licensing, posters

I have a big collection of film posters from the 40s-70s and I am working on a project where I want to print 100 posters into a book. I will credit the production company and mention all the info on the posters that I have plus all the info about actors in the film, director, etc.

Can I print this book in bulk and sell it or will there be a copyright issue?

Comment: do you have the rights to reproduce and sell the posters? Have you contacted the production company and asked _them_ that?

Answer (score 1):

I would say this would be an issue.  I would encourage you to reach out to every artist and request their permission to do so.  They may likely say yes or no but it would be best for you to create a template with their contact info requesting their approval.  You could lay something out in InDesign, export it as a PDF.   Open the PDF in Acrobat and create a form.  Go to each artist's site and send the PDF asking them to approve or deny the usage of the work using a radio selection.

> Can I print this book in bulk and sell it or will there be a copyright
>   issue?

Again, is this were to be released for free I do not think you would likely run into an issue but if you're seeking monetary value then I would say yes.  Anytime you plan to use someone else's work it's courtesy to get their permission before using it.